# Primefaces x-axis scale showing too broad value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm trying to run the Primefaces version 6.1 line chart YEARS example shown here

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/line.xhtml

The x axis values are Strings "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007" and "2008". Only 5 points in the scale. But when my line chart displays, it displays the x-axis scale from "2000" to "22000". This scale becomes too wide for the value to even display correctly.

When I use xAxis.setMin("2004") and xAxis.setMax("2008"), the scale narrows down, but not the values on the x-axis ("2004", "2005", "2006", "2007" and "2008") don't display at all.

Is there anything I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using LineChartSeries I used ChartSeries in the LineChartModel. And it now works.